# Динамическое добавление элементов к RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно добавлять элементы к RecyclerView при нажатии на кнопку без потери данных, но что-то идет не так. В каждом элементе есть EditText и еще один RecyclerView,в котором также происходит динамическое добавление элементов, содержащих EditText, которое я реализовал.

До нажатия на кнопку

[image: До нажатия на кнопку]

После нажатия на кнопку

[image: После нажатия на кнопку]

Вот код:

```
TaskAdapter taskAdapter;
FloatingActionButton floatButton;
ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> answersArray = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks, container, false);

    RecyclerView taskRecycle = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.create_recycle_view);
    taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter();
    taskRecycle.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
    taskRecycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    addTask();

    floatButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.add_task_button);
    floatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addTask();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void addTask() {
    saveData();
    taskAdapter.addTask();
    taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void saveData() {
    questions.clear();
    answersArray.clear();
    for (TaskHolder holder : taskAdapter.tasks) {
        questions.add(holder.question.getText().toString());
        holder.saveData();
        answersArray.add(holder.answerStrings);
    }
}


private class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskHolder> {

    ArrayList<TaskHolder> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    int taskSize = 0;

    @Override
    public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.creating_task_pattern, parent, false);
        TaskHolder holder = new TaskHolder(v);
        tasks.add(holder);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position < questions.size()) {
            tasks.set(position, holder);
            holder.answerAdapter.answers.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < answersArray.get(position).size(); i++)
                holder.addAnswer();
            holder.answerStrings = answersArray.get(position);
            holder.answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else {
            tasks.add(holder);
            holder.question.setText("");
            holder.answerAdapter.answers.clear();
            holder.answerAdapter.answerSize = 2;
            holder.answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return taskSize;
    }

    void addTask() {
        taskSize++;
    }
}

class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    EditText question;
    RecyclerView answerRecyclerView;
    AnswerAdapter answerAdapter;
    ImageView addTaskIcon;
    ArrayList<String> answerStrings = new ArrayList<>();

    TaskHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        question = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        answerRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.answer_recycle_view);
        answerAdapter = new AnswerAdapter();
        answerRecyclerView.setAdapter(answerAdapter);
        answerRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(itemView.getContext()));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            addAnswer();

        addTaskIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_answer_button);
        addTaskIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addAnswer();
            }
        });
    }

    void saveData() {
        answerStrings.clear();
        for (EditText et : answerAdapter.answers)
            answerStrings.add(et.getText().toString());
    }

    void addAnswer() {
        saveData();
        answerAdapter.addAnswer();
        answerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class AnswerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnswerHolder> {

        int answerSize = 0;
        ArrayList<EditText> answers = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void onViewRecycled(AnswerHolder holder) {
            super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public AnswerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.creating_answer_pattern, parent, false);
            return new AnswerHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(AnswerHolder holder, int position) {
            if (position < answerStrings.size()) {
                holder.answer.setText(answerStrings.get(position));
                answers.set(position, holder.answer);
            }
            else {
                answers.add(holder.answer);
                holder.answer.setText("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() { return answerSize; }

        void addAnswer() { answerSize++; }
    }

    class AnswerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        EditText answer;
        View removeIcon;
        AnswerHolder(View viewItem) {
            super(viewItem);
            answer = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.patterns_answer);
            removeIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Что нужно изменить, чтобы не терять данные?

Comment: А какой вопрос?

Comment: Добавление работает не корректно: теряется информация

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что надо вместо обновления всех элементов, что в свою очередь сотрет все текущие данные в EditText

```
taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

обновлять только 1 последний элемент

```
taskAdapter.notifyItemChanged(taskAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

Короче говоря addTask должна выглядеть так

```
private void addTask() {
    saveData();
    taskAdapter.addTask();
    taskAdapter.notifyItemChanged(taskAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
}
```